# how to parse heterogeneous json array in android

Tags: android, json

I am making android webservice application in this I am getting json response by hitting url.
If I get normal json array I will create one pojo class for json object.After that I set in pojo class.
my problem is I am getting heterogeneous json object array so how can I set values in pojo class please help me.

json:

```
[

{
  "name":"ram"
  "age" :"20"
}
{
  "school":"ashram"
  "country":"india" 
}
{
  "name":"syam"
  "age" :"40"
}
{
  "school":"bashyam"
  "country":"pakistan" 
}


]
```

pojo for name and age:

```
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: i think your json array not formated.